# How do i run a python function at a certain timestamp time. Without outside software?

Tags: python, function, unix, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I want to tell a python script to run a certain function when a certain timestamp time happens

I have already looked for running time specific functions
but i could not find anything that answered this specific question about
counting time stamps

```py
#input is number of days till due date
dueDate = int(input('Days until it is due: '))

#86400 seconds in a day
days = dueDate * 86400

#gets current time stamp time 
currentT = int(time.time())

#gets the timestamp for due date 
alarm = days+currentT
```

the aim is to find the python function which can run another function from within the script at when a specified future time stamp occurs

Comment: Without outside software? Can you install python module using pip?

Comment: Yes I can!  What do you recommend?

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Schedule](https://pypi.org/project/schedule/) is a good python module for doing this.

**Usage: (From Documentation)**

Install

```
$ pip install schedule
```

Usage

```
import schedule
import time

def job():
    print("I'm working...")

schedule.every(10).minutes.do(job)
schedule.every().hour.do(job)
schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(job)
schedule.every(5).to(10).minutes.do(job)
schedule.every().monday.do(job)
schedule.every().wednesday.at("13:15").do(job)
schedule.every().minute.at(":17").do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: it is 24 hours time for the

Comment: `schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(job)
`

Answer (score 1):

Build into python is the `sched` module. [Here](https://bip.weizmann.ac.il/course/python/PyMOTW/PyMOTW/docs/sched/index.html) is a pretty good write-up on it, and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html) is the official documentation. With `scheduler.enter` you can schedule with a delay, and with `scheduler.enterabs` you can schedule for a specific time.

```py
import sched
import time

scheduler = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

def print_event(name):
    print('EVENT:', time.time(), name)

now = time.time()
print('START:', now)

scheduler.enterabs(now+2, 2, print_event, ('first',))
scheduler.enterabs(now+5, 1, print_event, ('second',))

scheduler.run()
```

Outputs:

```
START: 1287924871.34
EVENT: 1287924873.34 first
EVENT: 1287924874.34 second
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just sleep the script for that long.

```
time.sleep(alarm)
```

Source: [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep)

Comment: While this is functional, it is technically not a native scheduling functionality. It would be bothersome to schedule more than one task with `time.sleep()`, unfortunately.

Comment: I interpreted this to mean he wanted a builtin function to accomplish his goal. I never said that time.sleep(alarm) was an ideal solution to the `inferred` request. :)

Comment: Fair enough! :)